# Memory management in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a class where i have define a array as a retain property such as:

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *temp;

can i use the self.temp = self.temp;
if yes can any one tell setter method for this and step by step implementation for this
looking forward from here.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you use self.temp = self.temp? That doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: If we do then what will happen??

Comment: - (void) setVarid:(id) newValue {
if (var != newValue) {
[var release];
var = newValue;
[newValue retain];
} what will happen to that case.
}

Comment: If you write self.temp = self.temp then nothing whatsoever will happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a setter method declare your `NSMutableArray` in your header file:

```
{
    NSMutableArray *temp;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *temp;
```

And then in the main file make sure you call this after the `@implementation MyClass`:

```
@synthesize temp;
```

This gives you your getter and setter methods so from outside this class you can call `MyClass.temp = ...;`

Comment: - (void) setVarid) newValue {
if (var != newValue) {
[var release];
var = newValue;
[newValue retain];
}
} That will be the setter method,please tell me how this will implemented step by step.

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't help at all! I doubt it would even compile. You don't need to create your own setter methods. Just use what I posted in the answer!